# Does anyone know why this subscript is out of range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use this levenshtein function to pull names into an array and group similar names together so that i can easily identify misspelled duplicates. The line in question starts and ends with ***

```
Function LevenshteinArray(ByVal s1 As String, ByVal s2 As String) As Integer
    ' Implementation of Levenshtein distance using arrays for improved performance
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim cost As Integer
    Dim len1 As Integer
    Dim len2 As Integer
    Dim array1() As Integer
    Dim array2() As Integer
    
    len1 = Len(s1)
    len2 = Len(s2)
    
    ReDim array1(0 To len1)
    ReDim array2(0 To len2)
    
    For i = 0 To len1
        array1(i) = i
    Next i
    
    For j = 1 To len2
        array2(0) = j
        For i = 1 To len1
            cost = Abs(StrComp(Mid(s1, i, 1), Mid(s2, j, 1), vbTextCompare))
        Next i
        For i = 0 To len1
          If i <= len2 Then
            array1(i) = array2(i)
          End If
        Next i
    Next j
    

     LevenshteinArray = ***array2(len1)***
End Function
```

Comment: array2 is being indexed by i which is related to len1 and there is not check that len2<= Len1?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this , could you possibly give an example of how this should look in the code please?

Comment: For your code to work correctly you need to make sure that the indexes (i,j) can be accommodated by the size of Array1 and Array2.  So after len2=len(S2) add an if statement that does a check using len1 and len2.  As an aside, your code would be much easier to understand if you used meaningful names for your variables rather than i,k len1 len2 etc.  The length of variable names makes no difference to the speed of execution but can considerable reduce the amount of debugging time.  .  Please also install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and pay attention to the Code Inspections.

Comment: I made edits to the script now the error is occurring on the very last line.